# How to modify the source of an installed package in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

How do I modify the source of an installed package in Heroku? It's a django app, but I suppose it shouldn't make much of a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses Git to manage your source code. Please see the quickstart guide at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart.

You will have to install Heroku Toolbelt, which is a command-line tool. With that application, you will be able to manage and deploy your heroku application.

If you ment 3rd-party addons, I think these are submodules, so you may not be able to modify them.

Comment: The django app was actually installed via requirements.txt. Should I have a local copy of the source code and push that through instead? I was hoping to find a way to just cd into the source code directory and make a change. Perhaps that's the linux way and not the heroku way of doing things?

Comment: Correct, afaik only this method works, your should push your own source copy.